# Problem with the orientation of dialoge when it is open

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to create a dialog that have horizontal buttons on the screen horizontal and vertical buttons on the vertical screen. I added this two xmls to Resources (normal view [layout] and landscape[layout-land]). When I open this dialog, everything works well (vertically and horizontally it looks as it should), however, when I have the dialog opened and I rotate the screen. The dialog rotates correctly but the buttons remain in the same state as when opened (does not load a second xml file).

Anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

```
var dialog = new SingleAlertDialog();
dialog.Show(activitiesTop, "tag");
```

Dialog:

```
    public class SingleAlertDialog : DialogFragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if (inflater == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inflater));

        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.general_dialog, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

I found a solution that you can use OnConfigurationChanged but I have a problem with orientation when starting the dialog

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. Did you try to reload the dialog?

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: I would rather put everything in a user control and change that control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If just want to change layout when orientation chanegd, not need to use `OnConfigurationChanged` .

You can create a `layout-land` folder below `Resources` folder , and add `general_dialog.xml` (with the same name bellow `layout`) inside it :

[image]

Now the layout of dialog will change based on orientation when opened .

**Note** : This should be tested in a physical device .

==========================Update=============================

If need to use `OnConfigurationChanged` method to do special things when orientation changes ,

```
public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Portrait)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Portrait");
    }
    else if (newConfig.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Landscape)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Landscape");
    }
}
```

Nedd to add `ConfigurationChanges` inside the Activity as follow:

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true,ConfigurationChanges =Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation|Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
```

Comment: I did it but it doesn't work when I open dialog and rotating screen.

Comment: @Haze Have a try with my sample project : https://www.dropbox.com/s/m2pq36p6qxbys3l/AppAndroidDiaglog.rar?dl=0

Comment: @Haze You also can share your sample project link here . I will check that .

Comment: May I ask you to add it to github?

Comment: @Haze Here is the github link : https://github.com/john-heaven/AppAndroidDiaglog

Comment: The reason for this problem was wrong ConfigurationChanges settings

Comment: @Haze Glad found the reason ! I have updated answer about `ConfigurationChanges`  , you can have a look at that. If answer be helpful , remember to vote it up when you have time :-)